# Merge & Create unique fail in one statement

Tags: neo4j

Why can't I use a create unique in a Merge ? Neo4j returns "unknown error "

```
Merge (o:Ot {name:"md2"} )
MERGE (pd:PD { p:"23"})
MERGE (tg:Ot {name:"XXX"})
MERGE (pi:PI { id:"123"}) 
WITH o,pi,target,pd
Create UNIQUE (o)-->(pi)-->(pd) , (pi)-->(tg)
RETURN o,pi,pd,tg
```

Comment: Do you also have indexes or constraints on your `:Label(property)` pairs that you use in your merges? Not sure you really need create unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have `target` in your `WITH` clause. It should probably be `tg`.
2. Whenever you `CREATE` a relationship between 2 nodes, you have to specify at least the relationship type.

This query, for example, will work:

```
MERGE (o:Ot {name:"md2"})
MERGE (pd:PD { p:"23"})
MERGE (tg:Ot {name:"XXX"})
MERGE (pi:PI { id:"123"}) 
WITH o,pi,tg,pd
CREATE UNIQUE (o)-[:x]->(pi)-[:y]->(pd), (pi)-[:z]->(tg)
RETURN o,pi,pd,tg
```

Comment: Thanks, weird as I swear I tried that, but I was modifying my Cypher alot to see what would work, & forgot to take out the target.

Comment: Actually, I see I tried your query, but didnt know the rule #2 you stated. Where did you read about that rule ? I dont remember seeing that in the docs

Comment: See [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.6/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/RelationshipType.html).